# JPA 2.1 - Strange behaviour with a one to one relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour with a one to one relationship. I have a one to one relationship between two entities: GeographicalLocation and IdentityDocument. In this relationship GeographicalLocation is the parent entity. The relationship is owned by the IdnetityDocument entity. Here is the JPA implementation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="GEOGRAPHICAL_LOCATION")
public class GeographicalLocation implements Serializable
{
  private Long id;
  ...

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "GEOGRAPHICAL_LOCATION_ID")
  public Long getId()
  {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id)
  {
    this.id = id;
  }
  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="IDENTITY_DOCUMENT")
public class IdentityDocument implements Serializable
{
  private Long id;
  ...
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "IDENTITY_DOCUMENT_ID")
  public Long getId()
  {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id)
  {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @OneToOne
  @MapsId
  @JoinColumn(name = "IDENTITY_DOCUMENT_ID")
  public GeographicalLocation getPlaceOfIssue()
  {
    return placeOfIssue;
  }

  public void setPlaceOfIssue(GeographicalLocation placeOfIssue)
  {
    this.placeOfIssue = placeOfIssue;
  }
```

This generates the following database model:

[image]
Now, trying to persist these entities like this:

```
GeographicalLocation geographicalLocation = ...;
IdentityDocument identityDocument = ...;
geographicalLocationFacade.save(geographicalLocation);
identityDocument.setPlaceOfIssue(geographicalLocation);
identityDocumentFacade.save(identityDocument);
```

creates two records in the GEOGRAPHICAL_LOCATION table and none in the IDENTITY_DOCUMENT one.
[image]

What seems to happen is that persisting the offspring entity creates a record in the master table while persisting the master entity correctly creates a record in the master table and none in the offspring table. I tried to play with different scenario and to google around, but I still don't understand what might happen here.
Many thanks in advance to whoever can shade some light.
kind regards,
Nicolas

Comment: It turns out that avoiding using the JPA 2 derived IDs (i.e. MapsId) solves the problem. The one to one relationship becomes as follows:

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "GEOGRAPHICAL_LOCATION_ID", unique= true, nullable=true, insertable=true, updatable=true)
    public GeographicalLocation getPlaceOfIssue()
    {
      return placeOfIssue;
    }

This is not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in hibernate which i have experienced it too. Found that `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` was the reason. If you use AUTO instead of IDENTITY then it will work, but the main reason we use IDENTITY is to prevent the extra select query by hibernate to determine the max value of id, leaving it to the DB, which will be a trade off you have to do.

Comment: Thank you Samim for your reply. It makes sense. However, the reason I wanted to use MapsId was in fact to avoid an extra-select. If I need to replace IDENTITY by AUTO and to assume another extra-select, then it is not worth using MapsId. So, I'll keep the design as it is and I'm closing the case.
By the way, when you're saying that you experienced the same issue, do you mean with MySQL as well or with other different datasources ? And do you have any reference of this Hibernate bug ?

Comment: @Nicolas my datsource was mysql and i haven't seen anyone reporting it as a bug. Although i tried using MapsId but it couldn't make it work. Did u add mapsid to child entity?

Comment: Yes, I confirm MapsId shall be on the relationship owner, i.e. the child entity where the foreign key is.

Comment: @Nicolas ok i will again to implement it. Thank u